# Функция _gethe()

Tags: c++

Как используя функцию _getch() реализовать(задание с калькулятором из института):
1) вводим 1, потом 2, потом 3 и т.д. значения и они должны записываться в переменную, только нужно не складывать, а конкатенировать, string использовать запретили.
Консоль : `12345 Результат: int result: 12345`(в этом проблема большая).
2) а вторая проблема как это сделать с плавающей точкой,
в консоли: `1234.6 Результат double: 1234.6`

Comment: Как можно конкатінировать строки или символы не используя результирующих строк? Вы не правильно поняли задание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Записывайте в массив

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char a[100] = {0};
    char t;
    int enterCode = 10;
    do {
      t = getchar();
      a[i] = t;
      ++i;
    }while(t != enterCode);
    cout<<a<<endl;
}
```